# Divide-and-conquer: Polynomial multiplication time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, multiplication, divide-and-conquer

When I was learning the divide and conquer approach, I came to this example (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-two-polynomials-2/) about polynomial multiplication. I cannot understand why the time required to add four results (subproblems) is Theta(n). I thought the addition only takes constant time. Why linear time? Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: It is an addition of polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. But here "to add all results" means the sum of multiplies of each power of `x` together to find the final result which is a polynomial, i.e., the sum of multiplies of `x`, `x^2`, ..., `x^n`. In this sense, the sum of the four polynomials with power of `O(n)`, takes `O(n)`.